# Can a NHibernate join be constrained from two separate entities?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I need to build an HQL query that uses the same entity twice, but with different constaints coming from previous entities.

For example:

```
select count(distinct a.id),
    count(disintct b.id),
    count(distinct c.id)
from
    EntityA a
left join a.Children b
left join a.Children c with c.SomeConstraint = b.SomConstraint
```

However, when I try to do this I get an exception saying that I have two entities in my with clause.

How can I express this concept in HQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in HQL right now.

If your with clause, the only things that are allowed currently are the joined entity and the entity that you're joining from.